# Unhandled Exception with Using statement

Tags: c#

From what I am reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) if you instantiate something inside a using statement than it should catch any exceptions and skip the code block. I am still seeing unhandled exceptions happen for file not found with this:

```
        using (TextReader sv = File.OpenText(@"sv\.sv"))
        {
            char[] k = { ':' };
            lastWsp = sv.ReadLine().Split(k)[1];
        }
```

Am I  misunderstanding the MSDN article or do I need to set a switch in the compiler?

Comment: Could you please copy over the section which you think is saying that?

Comment: From the docs:  "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs **while you are calling methods on the object**."  Using will not handle any exceptions that occur when instantiating the object.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway try throwing an exception from the method and call it from using.

Comment: Using is not handling any exceptions. It only calls Dispose method on IDisposable object when there is an unhandled exception.

Comment: @Selman22 - I'm not sure what you trying to say.  If an exception occurs during the instantiation of the TextReader (in this case), there will be nothing to Dispose.  The `using` statement doesn't handle exceptions.  If an exception occurs inside the body of the using, then the TextReader is guaranteed to be Disposed, but the exception will still not be handled.

Comment: Your comment was misleading.Like you were saying it will handle exception if the exception occurs while calling a method.Like you said  _The using statement doesn't handle exceptions._ would be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` translates into `try-finally` block, **it doesn't have `catch`**, so you are misunderstanding the article. It will not `catch` any exception, It will only make sure to dispose the object in case of an exception.

In your case since it a `FileNotFound` exception, your object will not be initialized.

Your code would translate into something like:

```
{
    TextReader sv = null;
    try
    {
        sv = File.OpenText(@"sv\.sv");
        char[] k = { ':' };
        lastWsp = sv.ReadLine().Split(k)[1];
    }
    finally
    {

        if(sv != null)
            sv.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In the above code in case of exception, it will try to dispose your object `sv`. But the exception will remain *unhandled* .

Since in your code, the exception is `FileNotFound` your object `sv` will remain null *(uninitialized)* and hence there will be no reason to call `Dispose`. But imagine if you have valid file path, and you get an exception at `sv.ReadLine().Split(k)[1];` then it will dispose your `TextReader` `sv`, and that exception will propagate up in the hierarchy because there is no `catch` block.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are misunderstanding the article.

`using` declares that the resource will be closed with `Dispose` regardless of any exceptions thrown within the block. It will not catch the exceptions for you.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN article is saying that even if exception is thrown from within the using block you have a guarantee that `.Dispose()` will be called on, in your case, object `sv`. Thats all it says and in addition to that, you are given the instructions on how to achieve that using `try` and `finally`:

> You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block

So it seems you misinterpreted the article.